# Equivalent in Objective c of BeanUtils.copyProperties.

Tags: java, objective-c, inheritance

I would like to know if they have an equivalent in Objective C of the JAVA's methode "BeanUtils.CopyProperties(bean1, Bean2);" ?

Or other solution, i would like to cast motherObject to childObject :

```
@interface motherBean : NSObject{ ...}
@interface childBean : motherBean { ...}

motherBean m = [motherBean new];
childBean f = m;
```

With the first tests it's work but I have a warning : "incompatible pointer types returning ...";

---

I use WSDL2Objc and it generate bean, and the name of it can change between 2 generation :-/

### I prefere to work with the child and just change the name in her definition

Thanks

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method BeanUtils.copyProperties

```
//.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@interface BeanUtils : NSObject

+(void)copyProperties:(id)src dest:(id)dest;

@end
```

---

```
//.m
#import "BeanUtils.h"

@implementation BeanUtils

+(void)copyProperties:(id)src dest:(id)dest {

    NSLog(@"classeSrc=%@ dst=%@", [src class], [dest class]);
    if(src == NULL || dest == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    Class clazz = [src class];
    u_int count;

    objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList(clazz, &count);
    NSMutableArray* propertyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
    {
        NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        [propertyArray addObject:propertyName];

        //on verifie que la prop existe dans la classe dest
         objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty([dest class], [propertyName UTF8String]);
        if(prop != NULL) {
            id result = [src valueForKey:propertyName];
            [dest setValue:result forKey: propertyName];
        }
        else {
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"La propriété %@ n'existe pas dans la classe %@",propertyName, [dest class] ];
        }
    }
    free(properties);    
}

@end
```

---

call :

```
EleveBean  *eleveBean = [EleveBean new];
eleveBean.nom = @"bob";
eleveBean.prenom = @"john";
tns1_EleveBean *tnsEleve = [tns1_EleveBean new];

[BeanUtils copyProperties:eleveBean dest:tnsEleve];
STAssertEquals(eleveBean.nom, tnsEleve.nom, @"");
STAssertEquals(eleveBean.prenom, tnsEleve.prenom, @"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at commons-beanutils package.  It has lots of property method for you to copy stuff.  In particular:

```
PropertyUtils.copyProperties(bean1, bean2);
```

However, as to your second question, you're trying to downcast an instance of a parent class to a child class?

I'm not sure how that would be legal in any OO language.  Sure you can forcibly cast:

```
// This is not legal because you can't case from one class to anther
// unless the actual instance type (not the declared type of the variable,
// but the constructed type) is either the casted class or a subclass.
Parent p = new Parent();
Child c = (Child) p;
```

But you'd get a ClassCastException , since you can't treat an instance of a parent class as if it were a child class (only the other way around).  Either of these would be legal however:

```
// This is legal because you're upcasting, which is fine
Child c = new Child();
Parent p = c;

// This is legal because the instance "p" is actually an
// instance of the "Child" class, so the downcast is legal.
Parent p = new Child();
Child c = (Child) p;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that the reason why i m looking for equivalent of  BeanUtils.CopyProperties(bean1, Bean2); (or PropertyUtils.copyProperties(bean1, bean2) it's the same thinks) but in Objective c not in Java

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you could easily write the code to copy property values between  instances. It is easiest if you restrict properties to proper Objective-C properties (items declared using @property()) which is probably the best practice anyway. You can use the Objective-C runtime functions to get the list of all properties on a class (class_getPropertyList) and call property_getName() to get the property's name and call property_getAttributes() to make sure it is writeable. Then you can use NSObject's Key Value Coding to get and set the property values using valueForKeyPath: and setValueForKeyPath: respectively.

Some problems with you code example are that instances should be pointers. Second, you need an explicit cast since you are assigning an instance of a class to its super class. The reverse would not require a cast. That is probably why you are getting the warning.

Comment: I hoped that the method already exists. I write one and post here