# What is the Objective-C equivalent of Java BeanUtils.copyProperties?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a coredata model class(a subclass of NSManagedObject) which has a lot of properties. When I copy values from a DTO class to the coredata model class which have almost same properties, I would prefer to use copy utils like BeanUtils.copyProperties. Does anyone know if there is such a useful class in CocoaAPI.

```
"BeanUtils.copyProperties"

Copy the property values of the given source bean into the target bean. 

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
```

Comment: This looks similar..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884218/equivalent-in-objective-c-of-beanutils-copyproperties.

Comment: Sorry. I will close this question now.